# How to calculate YTC

Tags: bonds

Company A has a 20 year, $1000 face value bond with a 6% coupon interest paid semiannually, the bond currently has a yield to maturity of 5% and its callable in 19 years with a call premium of 1 years interest. What is the bond’s yield to call if it is purchased today?

a.  2.44%

b.  4.43%

c.  6.44%

d.  4.87%

Comment: See chapter 6 of you textbook: "Yield To Close Calculations"

Comment: @BobBaerker You mean "Yield to Call".

Comment: Giving you the answer isn't going to help. Show what calculations you have done and where you;'re stuck. If you're stuck in the beginning, remember that Yield is the same as IRR. Use the current value as the outflow, the coupons before the call as inflows, and the call price as the final inflow (as if the bond matured).